# Unable to Login to Ubuntu 16 via SSH using Ubuntu One Account

Tags: server, ssh, login

I just completed setting up Ubuntu 16 Core on a Raspberry PI 3.  I am not able to authenticate over ssh.  I created an Ubuntu One account and I added the SSH Keys I created using PuttyGen.  The set up completed and I can see on my firewall that the OS has successfully obtained an IP address from DHCP.  I checked the firewall logs and there are no packets coming from the RPI being dropped by the firewall.  It appears that Ubuntu One Account is not working and as the root account is disabled, I do not have an mechanism to troubleshoot this issue.

Thanks

Comment: How did you configure the keys ? How did you transfer the keys to the server if you do not have access ? What command are you running to connect ? How did you configure your ssh server ?

Comment: I used Putty Gen to generate the keys, then I pasted the keys into the SSH Keys Section on the Ubuntu One website. Then as part of the set up, I entered in the email address for my Ubuntu one account.  The setup would not continue until I entered in the Ubuntu One account and the added the SSH Keys to the website.  When the PI boots up, it says <ssh [username]@a.b.c.d>.  The set routine creates the user account using the Ubuntu One account.  The SSH server is activated as part of the image.  I can successfully connect using Putty.

Comment: So what is the problem ? " I can successfully connect using Putty" ? You want to connect with ssh ? Can you clarify your question .

Comment: The second sentance states "I am not able to authenticate over ssh."

Comment: Yes , but your comments also say "I can successfully connect using Putty" so again I am asking for clarification as Putty is connecting over ssh. So what is your problem ? you can connect with putty but not ssh on the command line ? What is your ssh command ?

Comment: I get the login prompt, but the OS/PAM/SSH is not accepting my Ubuntu One user ID and password.

Comment: Can you post the command you are running please ? It is difficult to help you as you are not providing much information. "So what is your problem ? you can connect with putty but not ssh on the command line ? What is your ssh command ?"

Comment: You might have this problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224066/how-to-convert-ssh-keypairs-generated-using-puttygenwindows-into-key-pairs-use